# how to create every day at 12 am new log file with current date VBScript

Tags: vbscript

```
strFileName1 = "D:\log.txt"
strContent = "" & Now & Space(2) & dir & vbCr & vbLf

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLogs = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName1, ForAppending, True)

objLogs.WriteLine(strContent)
objLogs.Close
```

Comment: The every day at 12 am can be achieved with a Scheduled Task

Comment: strFileName1 = "D:\log " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyy") & ".txt" getting error type mismatch

Comment: Sorry that is my fault, was thinking VBA, Here is what you can do in VBScript:  strFileName1 = "D:\log " & Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now) & "-" & Year(Now) & ".txt"

Comment: ya its working thanks a lot :) Sorceri

Comment: can we remove am and pm from date

Comment: 24hrs time formt

Comment: @SAH Please edit your question instead continuous commenting to describe your actual problem, so you can get an answer.